# Решение задачи путём динамического программирования

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Как из матрицы `A[n][n]` составить `B[n][n]` матрицу `(2 ≤ n ≤100)` ? . В которой `B[i][j]` элемент равен  максимальному элементу матрицы `A` , который справа ограничен диагональю проходящей на `A[i][j]`. Задачу переводил максимально близко по смыслу, но суть не до конца ясна. Требуется помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите - работаем по столбцам. Тогда первый столбец `B` просто равен первому столбцу `A`.

Далее в каждом следующем столбце `B` для элемента `B[i][j]` надо рассмотреть элементы `B[i-1][j-1]`, `B[i][j-1]`, `B[i+1][j-1]` и `A[i][j]` и выбрать максимальный из них.

Пишется очень просто :)

*По-моему, так*. (с) Пух

Примерно так (писал почти на C, не C++, и для константного размера):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

const int N = 4;
int A[N][N];
int B[N][N];

inline int get(int X[N][N], int r, int c)
{
    if (r<0 || r>=N || c<0 || c >=N) return INT_MIN;
    return X[r][c];
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand()%100;
            printf("%4d",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for(int c = 0; c < N; ++c)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < N; ++r)
        {
            int v0 = get(B,r-1,c-1);
            int v1 = get(B,r,  c-1);
            int v2 = get(B,r+1,c-1);
            int v3 = get(A,r  ,c  );
            v0 = (v0 > v1) ? v0 : v1;
            v2 = (v2 > v3) ? v2 : v3;
            B[r][c] = (v0 > v2) ? v0 : v2;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            printf("%4d",B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

}
```

Думаю, разберетесь сами. Комментариев по тому, что делает какая строка кода - не будет...

Comment: Почему первый столбец B равен А ?

Comment: Да потому что у вас отсекающие диагонали выделят только один элемент...

Comment: А чему равен INT_MIN ?

Comment: Грубо - аналог минус бесконечности для отсутствующих ячеек (например, когда смотрим на самом верху или слева...) - чтоб не обрабатывать их отсутствие, заменяем их фиктивными с заведомо не годящимся значением.